# jsoup statusCode won't print 404 error

Tags: java, jsoup

In my Java servlet, I want to perform some actions depending on the status code returned from a request to a url.

My code looks like this:

```
String source = "http://urltoparse.org/name/date";
boolean validQuery = jsoupHandler.sourceExists(source);

int statusCode = jsoupHandler.srcExists(source);
response.getWriter().println("stat: " + statusCode);
```

jsoupHandler:

```
public class JSoupHandler {
    public int srcExists(String source) throws IOException {
        Connection.Response resp = Jsoup.connect(source).execute();
        System.out.println("status" + resp.statusCode());
        return resp.statusCode();
    }
}
```

When the `statusCode == 200`, it prints

`stat: 200` in the browser and `status200` in my console for jsouphandler.

However, when I put in a source that should return a 404, like this:

```
String source = "http://urltoparse.org/name/date2";
```

The browser prints nothing and my console prints an error like this:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://urltoparse.org/name/date2
```

Why do the print statements for the browser and console both not print the status code?  I want to do something like

```
if (statusCode != 200) {
//do something
}
```

but I'm unable to get into this conditional statement.

I've looked at this link: [Jsoup error handling when couldn't connect to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619003/jsoup-error-handling-when-couldnt-connect-to-website)

but couldn't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
.ignoreHttpErrors(true)
```

to your request.

See API: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#ignoreHttpErrors-boolean-

Comment: I'm using Connection.Response, not Connection.Request, according to this:

'https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html#statusCode--' .statusCode() should return whatever the status code is, I'm not sure how I would get that if I used Connection.Request

Comment: `Jsoup.connect(source).execute();` is a request and you are storing the response. The request leads to the http error and by setting `Jsoup.connect(source).ignoreHttpErrors(true).execute();` you are telling Jsoup to ignore the http errors when connecting, otherwise Jsoup throws exceptions on http errors.